# How should I know when to use the Kanji/Hiragana for certain words?

Tags: kanji, kanji-choice

Apologies if this is not correctly formatted or if my grammer does not make sense. My 1st language is Chinese, not English. I am very sorry.

In many cases, I will see people type the same word differently. Often times, I will see あなた and then 貴方, or I will see おちゃ and お茶, or すし and 寿司。 Is there a way to know in what situations I should use which version of a word? Like, should I use a certain version in more formal situations or is one version more common/accepted than the other? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome, hope [these many posts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=when+hiragana+kanji) helps you.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!

Comment: おちゃ should be written お茶 pretty much always. おかし for お菓子 would be more common.